# Problems doing a get on a s3 bucket with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use the python sample code from amazon [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html#sig-v4-examples-get-auth-header)  to do a "GET with an Authorization Header" mechanism on a s3 bucket. The source code which I am using is below:

```
# AWS Version 4 signing example

# EC2 API (DescribeRegions)

# See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html
# This version makes a GET request and passes the signature
# in the Authorization header.
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac
import requests # pip install requests

# ************* REQUEST VALUES *************
method = 'GET'
service = 's3'
host = 's3.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'
endpoint = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/sample_object/foo'
request_parameters = ''

# Key derivation functions. See:
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-python
def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning

# Read AWS access key from env. variables or configuration file. Best practice is NOT
# to embed credentials in code.
access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
secret_key = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
    print 'No access key is available.'
    sys.exit()

# Create a date for headers and the credential string
t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope


# ************* TASK 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST *************
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

# Step 1 is to define the verb (GET, POST, etc.)--already done.

# Step 2: Create canonical URI--the part of the URI from domain to query
# string (use '/' if no path)
canonical_uri = '/sample_object/foo'

# Step 3: Create the canonical query string. In this example (a GET request),
# request parameters are in the query string. Query string values must
# be URL-encoded (space=%20). The parameters must be sorted by name.
# For this example, the query string is pre-formatted in the request_parameters variable.
canonical_querystring = request_parameters

# Step 4: Create the canonical headers and signed headers. Header names
# and value must be trimmed and lowercase, and sorted in ASCII order.
# Note that there is a trailing \n.
# amz_content_sha256 = hashlib.sha256('').hexdigest()
amz_content_sha256 = 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD'
canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-content-sha256:' + amz_content_sha256 + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'

# Step 5: Create the list of signed headers. This lists the headers
# in the canonical_headers list, delimited with ";" and in alpha order.
# Note: The request can include any headers; canonical_headers and
# signed_headers lists those that you want to be included in the
# hash of the request. "Host" and "x-amz-date" are always required.
signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date'

# Step 6: Create payload hash (hash of the request body content). For GET
# requests, the payload is an empty string ("").
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256('').hexdigest()

# Step 7: Combine elements to create create canonical request
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash


# ************* TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN*************
# Match the algorithm to the hashing algorithm you use, either SHA-1 or
# SHA-256 (recommended)
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request).hexdigest()


# ************* TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE *************
# Create the signing key using the function defined above.
signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)

# Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# ************* TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST *************
# The signing information can be either in a query string value or in
# a header named Authorization. This code shows how to use a header.
# Create authorization header and add to request headers
authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature

# The request can include any headers, but MUST include "host", "x-amz-date",
# and (for this scenario) "Authorization". "host" and "x-amz-date" must
# be included in the canonical_headers and signed_headers, as noted
# earlier. Order here is not significant.
# Python note: The 'host' header is added automatically by the Python 'requests' library.
headers = {'x-amz-date':amzdate, 'Authorization':authorization_header, 'x-amz-content-sha256':amz_content_sha256}


# ************* SEND THE REQUEST *************
request_url = endpoint

print '\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
print 'Request URL = ' + request_url
r = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers)

print '\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
print 'Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code
print r.text
```

I have correctly set the access id and secret access key. I used the same with boto python library and it seems to work when I list buckets, put objects etc. However when I use the above method I get back a 403 error saying "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." I am not sure what is wrong with the above method. Any pointers.?

Comment: http 403 means access forbidden.  By default, S3 will keep the bucket private to the bucket creator, unless you provide the correct access key using AWS SDK or make a change in S3 Bucket policies. To make a HTTP GET to S3 ,  you need to setup specific bucket policies to allow it.   It is a long topic, please read  S3 access control  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html

Comment: This is serverfault.com issues, please post it there to get better response. For a quick hint, you need to add anonymous access for to enable connection :  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html
After done the testing, add condition key to prevent unwanted access to your bucket.

Comment: I think you are not including the action in signature calculation. You have set `request_parameters` to empty string where as the example has action in it. Worth checking.

Comment: @Buchi I don't need to here because this is with s3 and the example was a ec2 service.

Comment: @Buchi is right: you need a line for `request_parameters`/`canonical_querystring` in the `canonical_request`. Even if it is blank, the newline is required.

Comment: @ataylor Well, I just tried adding a new line character as part of request_parameters. That didn't help either :(

Comment: @PradeepNayak As per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html it seems like we need to include Action in signature calculation. So, does it matter if it's ec2 or s3? I think you need to put whatever action you are doing in GET, IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canonical headers should have a trailing newline and `canonical_request` needs the `canonical_querystring` line even if it is blank.  Also, use `UNSIGNED_PAYLOAD` for `amz_content_sha256` for GET requests.

Here's a working example.  It gets a file called `key` on an S3 bucket in the `us-west-2` region called `bucket`:

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac
import requests
method = 'GET'
service = 's3'
host = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-west-2'
endpoint = 'http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
request_parameters = ''

def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning

access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
secret_key = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
    print 'No access key is available.'
    sys.exit()

t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

canonical_uri = '/bucket/key'
canonical_querystring = request_parameters
canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD' + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'
signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date'
payload_hash = 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD'
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request).hexdigest()
signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature
headers = {'x-amz-date':amzdate, 'x-amz-content-sha256': 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD', 'Authorization':authorization_header}
request_url = endpoint + canonical_uri

print '\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
print 'Request URL = ' + request_url
r = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers)

print '\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
print 'Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code
print r.text
```

Comment: Still no luck. I added the new line at the end of it and used UNSIGNED_PAYLOAD for the amz_content_sha256 as well. I have the correct bucket policy as well.

Comment: I have updated the code to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: do I need `x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD` if I put an object to `s3`?